# asp.net nested repeaters and rendering issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am rendering 1000+ records on a web page using nested repeaters. The problem i am facing is that it takes too much time to render the data on page.

Here is the concept layout of repeaters.

> -Main
>
> ```
> -Level 1
>
>         -Level 2
>
>                 -Level 3
>
>                 -Level 3
>
>         -Level 2
>
> -Level 1
> ```
>
> -Main

When page loads Main and level 1 rows are showing. when user click on level 1 row, level 2 row appears and by clicking on level 2, level 3 row shows up.

I am loading data to all the repeaters at once and hiding/showing the level 2 and level3 rows using jQuery.

The problem is that i get data within a second from database but it takes too long to render.

One solution is that i load Main and Level 1 row at the page load and show level 2 and 3 rows based on user click.

Is there any other way to improve the performance?

Thanks in advance

I am loading the data onto page at once and then hiding Level 2 and Level 3.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you improve performance if you don't post any code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying over 1000 records (assuming any normal complexity in each record) is going to take a long time no matter what. Here are some suggestions:

1. Split the Level 1 records across several pages (like Google results) where users can click a next page/previous page button, and/or let users select a page index from a drop-down list and load that page's results from the cache/session variable.
2. When users select a particular item in Level 1, redirect them to a separate page that loads all Level 2 items, and do the same thing for Level 3.
3. Use AJAX to build your Level 2 and Level 3 records only after a user clicks on that particular level.
4. Filter your results based on some options that the user must select before you go out to the database and build this page.

Comment: Great! thanks jwiscarson for the helpful post. I am certainly following your tips and can see a improvement in performance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to improve the performance?

Disable viewstate.  And only pull down the records you need.  Page the results.

Also, can't you just make Ajax call to pull the nested/detailed rows down "as needed".

Comment: Will disabling viewstate actually improve render performance?  I know it will decrease page size, and therefore decrease time "over the wire".  Perhaps there's some under-the-covers dependency between viewstate and rendering I'm not aware of?